# Multitple Image upload can not save descriptions into database. How to fix this?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to create a multiple image upload with description on each image. I have used a jquery coe that allows me to add fields on demand. However, even though the images are uploaded and saved into DB, in the description column I get `Array[0]` instead of the actual description..

How can I fix this?

**This is the HTML**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>

  <div><input type="file" name="file_array[]"><input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Write Description"></div>

  </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload all files">
</form>
```

**and here is the upload.php**

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "upload/".$name_array[$i])){
        mysql_query("INSERT into projects (`image`,`description`) VALUES('$name_array[$i]','$_POST[description][$i]') ");
            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
        } else {
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that was a typo mistake?

Comment: @shehary I have fixed the typo, however nothing changed

Comment: Use this query `mysql_query("INSERT into projects (`image`,`description`) VALUES('".$name_array[$i]."','".$_POST['description'][$i]."') ");
`

Comment: @Saty thank you! please post it as an answer so as to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your `description` in `quotes`. So your query would be.

```
mysql_query("INSERT into projects (`image`,`description`) VALUES('".$name_array[$i]."','".$_POST['description'][$i]."') ");
```